# How to simply repeat/duplicate the POST request in Node.js but change the URL?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and would like to duplicate the request, change few options and then rerun/repeat it multiple times (changing parameters each time).

I can catch the original request with on request event. Then I would like to simply duplicate this, change few parameters and rerun it multiple times.

page.on('request', request => {

// I capture the original request here

});

What is the best way to duplicate this request, change few attributes and repeat it?